# Disable SAP file open dialog confirmation

Tags: windows, security, sap

SAP shows a security related dialog when accessing files like this:

[image: SAP File open confirmation dialog]

Since I want to perform automated system tests, I'd like to get rid of this warning.

I know I can check the checkbox and remember my decision, but the filenames are generated and will be different in each test. Is there some global setting do allow all files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the SAP Options and expand the "Security" tab.

The easy way would be to change the status to `Disabled`.

The safer way would be to open the `security configuration` in this tab and to enter manually the folders or disk which you want SAP having access to.

---

Also see in `SAP Security Guide Chapter 2.5`:
[SAP Security Guide](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/002444be-7018-2d10-e18e-a8c537198ef6?quicklink=index&overridelayout=true)

Comment: Thanks. I am on a test system only, so disabling completely is fine for me.

Comment: No worries. I have also been never setting up a security configuration, but just used `disabled`.

Comment: Disabling it, I watched it in Process Monitor. It seems this sets the Registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAP\SAPGUI Front\SAP Frontend Server\Security`, DWORD SecurityLevel = 0 and DWORD DefaultAction  =0

Comment: That's true, I added the link for the SAP security guide, where you can read that. However, in my opinion I don't want to get confronted with registry and stuff :-)